# How to enable non-admin user to use powershell extensions?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to enable a specific non admin user to use PowerShell extensions without giving them admin privileges.

So far, according to the [PowerShell ISE Security Documentation](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/security.html), I have given all the necessary permissions to that user to following items in Core database:

`\content\Applications\PowerShell` and all its descendants and also to 
`\content\Applications\Content Editor\Context Menues\Default` and all its descendants.

However, when that user click on PowershellIse, he gets logged out and is unable to use it.

My question is that what permissions do I need to set, apart from what I already have and is it possible at all to access and use PowershellIse for non-admin users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I recommend you not allow the user to click the PowerShell ISE and Console shortcuts. Those are interfaces designed for a Developer or Admin.

As noted in the book, the **Script** menu is allowed for users not associated with the `sitecore\Sitecore Limited Content Editor` since a *deny read* is set.

[image: Visible by Default]

Ribbon commands are visible after you run the integration sync found in the ISE. See this [page](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content-editor.html) for more details.

You can configure rules on the script item to alter visibility and enabled state. In the script you'll want to add in a [`UserSwitcher`](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/commands/New-UsingBlock.html) to provide the necessary elevated privileges.

```powershell
$elevatedUser= Get-User -Identity "sitecore\ElevatedUser"

New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher $elevatedUser) {
    # Run commands that required the elevated access.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for letting me know! I will surely try that and will let you know! Thanks again :)

Comment: Michael, would giving a user the Developer role also work?

Comment: Yes, Developers should see all the interfaces.

Comment: @MichaelWest - Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!!