# Getting New-Item : AddFromTemplate - Add access required when trying to add new workflows

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have written a SPE which would create a workflow on button click. This is working fine with admin account. If content author is trying to create a workflow then its giving following error,

[image]

and the content authors are not able to add a new workflow. I have followed the below article to create the workflow batch.

My Script:

```
# If Valid workflow name then create new workflow
function Create-New-Workflow()
{
    
    Param([System.String] $newWorkflowPath,[System.String] $wfName)
    try {
     New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {
            $newWorkflowItem = New-Item -Path $wfpath -ItemType $workflowbranchTemplate
            
        }
       Show-Alert("Workflow  $wfName created successfully!") 
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException],[System.IO.IOException]{
  
    Show-Alert("Unable to create workflow $wfName")
}
}
```

This line is throwing error,

```
New-Item -Path $wfpath -ItemType $workflowbranchTemplate
```

Comment: Do you have a sample script, trimmed down to exactly what is needed, that you can share with your question? It's quite possible that you need to use a `UserSwitcher` to delegate access.

Comment: I have updated my question with script. I have tried using Security disabler still I am facing access denied issue.

Comment: You'll want to try something like this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8873/95

Comment: I can see there was no create access provided to the user. So they were not able to create any new items. However Userswitch resolved the issue. Thanks Michael